# Plotting Average Length of Brownian Motion Realization

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a function for a brownian motion:

```
mu , sig = 0 , 1 # normal dist 
mu_s = 0 # mu in SDE
sig_s = 1 #sig in SDE
S0 = 10 # starting price of stock
n , m = 1000, 20 # paths = n = how many simulations, m  for discritization
T = 1 # year
dt = 1 # each dt is one day


def ABM(n,m,S0,mu,sigma,dt):
    np.random.seed(999) 
    mu_s = mu # mu in SDE
    sig_s = sigma #sig in SDE
    S0 = S0 # starting price of stock
    n , m = n, m # paths = n = how many simulations, m  for discritization


    sig_db = sig_s*np.sqrt(dt)*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (n,m+1))
    mu_dt = mu_s*dt*np.ones([n,m+1])

    sig_db[:,0] = 0 # set first column to zero
    mu_dt[:,0] = 0

    dS = mu_dt + sig_db
    S = S0 + np.cumsum(dS,axis=1)


    return n,m,S   
n,m,S = ABM(1000,20,10,0,1,1)
```

Which works fine for plotting separate realizations on one plot:

```
index  = np.arange(0,m+1)*np.ones([n,m+1]) # create indices as S_0, S_1, S_2
plt.plot(index.T,S.T)
```

but now I'd like to plot the average path length of those realizations for each time step and I'm not sure how to go about it. The expectation of arithmetic brownian motion is E(S)=S_0 + \mu*t which leads me to think I should be using `np.mean()` in some way but I can't seem to get it.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The matrix S consists of n realizations, you get the E(S(t)) by averaging along the realizations, i.e.

```
EE = np.mean(S, axis = 0)
```

Similarly, you can get the variance, also a function of time, via

```
np.mean((S - EE)**2, axis = 0)
```